# Change the Location of DefaultPage in Universal App

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

How can I change the location of the default `MainPage.xaml` in an `Universal Windows App`? I want to have in the Windows and WindowsPhone Project a subfolder named "View" where I save the `MainPage.xaml` file like this example.

- Windows Project
 -- View
 --- MainPage.xaml

- WindowsPhone Project
 -- View
 --- MainPagePhone.xaml

- Shared Files
 -- Model
 -- ViewModel
 -- App.xaml

With that structure I have a problem in the `App.xaml.cs` that the `MainPage` can't be find.

```
if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments))
{
    throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need to give different names to your files, use MainPage for both phone and pc project and put MainPage.xaml inside the view folder.
The Universal App will be aware of which platforms it runs on and it will load the right page accordingly.
You need to create the view folder and the MainPage.xaml file in both projects.
Delete every MainPage.xaml files outside of the View folder.

Then navigate to your App.xaml.cs shared file.

Look into the `onLaunched` method, you should find something like this at the end of the method:

```
if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments))
{
    throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
}
```

This is where your project try to load the page. MainPage should be marked as an error because we're missing the reference.

So, add this at the top of the App.xaml.cs page:

```
using NameOfYourProjectHere.View;
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: i tried this, but I can't add the namespace in the App.xaml.cs. It gaves the error: The namespace "View" is not available

Comment: I tried too, and it let me to import the namespace only if View is present in both the windows phone and windows project. Post some screen of your project structure  please

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have different names (mainWinPage / mainPhonePage ) you have to tell him which one to take, every time you use it in Shared-Project:

```
#include yournamespace.Views;
..

#if WINDOWS_APP
if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainWinPage), e.Arguments))
...
#else // or #if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPhonePage), e.Arguments))
...
#endif
```

or just use same names, makes it easier.